# MODx crawling issue is not a duplicate of Why aren't search engines indexing my content?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Webmasters Stack Exchange post: [MODx issue, cannot be crawled](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140542/modx-issue-cannot-be-crawled)

My post was closed for a reason of duplicate. It is very hard to me to solve my problem. I had been read entire post that was sophisticated of duplicate. There are nothing about **MODx** Issue or even about the problem of openning, but not able to be tested in pagespeed.google.com.

I cannot be sure, but it was 4th time i have been asking my question. first two times on google community, third on stack overflow, fourth on stack exchange webmasters. Please help me, it is makes me sad :(

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a lot of overlap with the marked duplicate, your question has other problems:

- It is very specific to your site. Questions that are specific to one website are closed as off-topic because they are unlikely to help future visitors. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting.
- Your problems are not clearly described. You say there is a 404 error, but you don't give an example path or say why you would expect that not to happen.

You can edit your question to:

- Differentiate your question from the marked duplicate. I think this should be fairly easy. Remove the part about not getting indexed and just focus the question on whether or not MODx makes your site uncrawlable.
- Rewrite the question so that it could be applicable to other sites with similar problems. We shouldn't need to check your site to understand the issue. Ideally you wouldn't even need to link to your site.
- Add more information about your issue.

Once you edit the question it will be evaluated for re-opening.  That is a process that can take a couple days.  You can ping me by mentioning `@StephenOstermiller` in a comment under your question and I'd be happy to expedite the process or request additional edits from you.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am new here, but almost 10 years experience of web dev. I want to help with issues too, not just to ask of mine problems, what should I read to become a professional of StackExchange forum?

Thank You be the way.

Comment: A good place to start is our [help center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help)